# How do you unlock Divas?

Tags: wwe-2k15, wwe-2k16

In WWE2K15/2K16, how do you unlock Divas (female playable wrestlers)? They have their own tab on the Roster so I know they are playable. Are they through the 2K Showcase, MyCareer, or something?

Comment: did this help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only unlock Divas via DLC or season pass.

- WWE 2K15 SEASON PASS PROGRAM will give you  Access to exclusive playable WWE Diva Paige.
- NXT ARRIVAL Will unlock Emma.

Here is were i have referenced this from http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/204408293-WWE-2K15-DLC-Breakdown